# Why would a company skip an HR interview?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, human-resources

What would make an established company hire someone without doing an HR interview (after several on-site technical interviews) ?

The interviewers said that there will be an HR interview, every mention of their hiring process mentions an HR interview, they have an HR department.

Comment: You seem to be asking a few questions all bundled up in one, which makes your question seem too vague to be on topic here. I noticed it got one down vote, which is probably a result of what I described. However, if you were to edit it a bit and narrow down your focus a) we could help you more and b) give you actual advice related to your specific situation.

Comment: Thanks a lot i tried to narrow it down a bit

Comment: In my experience it is unusual for a company to do HR interviews *after* the technical interview. The HR interview is almost always a screening process for the real interviews

Comment: Can you add a location tag please? Skipping the HR part of an interview where I live is basically skipping the smalltalk before the interview, while in other countries it might include skipping real employment constraints, like drug tests or criminal background checks.

Comment: @nvoigt What countries do drug tests and criminal background checks as part of a HR interview? Where I am from, drug tests during interviews would be... heavy-handed, and criminal background checks can't usually be done with an interview.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie I guess the country that "Julie in Austin" is from, according to her comments on answers. If I had to guess I'd say the US, but I don't have enough experience to say whether that's correct. Where I live, asking for a criminal background check without a specific reason would probably even be against some data protection laws, drug testing would be the weirdest thing I was ever asked and probably the end of the interview from my part. But other countries might be very different and that's why I asked for a country tag.

Answer (score 6):

No one can know specifically why in your case, but my guess is that they've decided it's unnecessary.

Every time I have been interviewed by HR, it's been a pre-screen that has covered things like: willingness to relocate, general information about the position and company, high-level compatibility check, and basically checking any other deal-breakers to save the hiring manager and team's time. If you've already done the technical interviews I can't really imagine what an HR interview would cover.

Comment: The "HR interview" can be any number of things. In my experience it's usually a more formal version of "we need you to pee in a cup". Since my earliest contacts with the in-house recruiter consisted of providing external document references, they just didn't both with much of anything for me.

Answer (score 2):

> Why would a company skip an HR interview?

It could be one of two things.

1. The technical interviewers felt confident enough that you were a good fit for the position and they have a good trust relationship with the HR interviewers that they want to move forward with you without needing HR's opinion.

or

2. The technical interviewers do not think you are a good fit and do not want to waste HR's time with someone who they ultimately do not want.

Comment: Does 1 happen often?

Comment: @user108147 I don't know, personally I have never been interviewed by HR for any position I have applied to but I know many people who have.  For technical positions I would guess that a HR interview would never be necessary after a technical interview but that all depends on the company.

Comment: One that has happened to me.
3. The local branch is a little less formal that the company as a whole and don't feel the need to go through every step as described by the main branch.

Comment: @user108147 - Yes. Not only was my HR interview skipped for my current job, my drug screen and criminal background check were also skipped. Some people have very "public" professional experience. Other than trying to keep my identity ... private ... I'm a pretty well-known character. Emphasis on "character" ;)

Comment: The OP stated _"What would make an established company hire someone.."_ - so I guess in that case the person is employed/hired already so point 2 of your answer wouldn't apply or I'm I missing something here?

Comment: or 3. HR is overworked and understaffed right now and decided to just cancel it.

Answer (score 0):

HR is not necessary for technical professions after adequate credentials are established and there is a definitive and immediate need in that professional

Comment: Well, as a counter-example, a candidate could be ineligible to work in the country. Why should "technical professions" be above HR involvement? Not having a HR interview is one thing, but skipping HR involvement is quite another.

Comment: @RJFalconer if person got to technical interview - he is eligible